# Why am I not able to click the web element using the following code, even though I can see that the controller is tracking the xpath?

Tags: java, selenium

[click here to check the page I am working on](http://www.amazon.in/s?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A976419031%2Cn%3A!976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cp_89%3AApple%2Cn%3A!976420031&bbn=1389432031&ie=UTF8)
The following is the java code:

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ref_2665398031']/li[4]/a/span[1](http://www.amazon.in/s?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A976419031%2Cn%3A!976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cp_89%3AApple%2Cn%3A!976420031&bbn=1389432031&ie=UTF8)")).click();

The element is actually in the left navigation pane.

Here when this particular statement is getting executed, I can see that browser is moving down, but it does not click that element.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code?

Comment: the java code for the particular element is <span class="refinementLink">50% Off or more</span>

Comment: Which browser do you use: Firefox, Crome, HtmlUnit ?

Comment: I am using chrome for automating, whereas to inspect the element I am using Firefox.

Comment: is your id `ref_2665398031` is comman every time or is it dynamic ?

Comment: Long time ago I used Selenium with HtmlUnit browser, and there I noticed, that it is important to click exactly on that HTML-Element that consume the event. For Example if there was a Button with a Span in and the event was registered for the Button, then it was important have selenium click the button but not the span. Maybe you have a similar issue, and you need to click the `<a>` but not the `<span>`

Comment: It is a common id for three elements.

Comment: Try These `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ref_2665398031']/li[4]/a/span[1]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);` lines and let me know if having same issue

Comment: it is also not working. As I am not that good in java script, can  u brief what we are trying to do in that piece of code. I was just trying to automate this page "http://www.amazon.in/s?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Cn%3A976419031%2Cn%3A!976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cp_89%3AApple%2Cn%3A!976420031&bbn=1389432031&ie=UTF8". In this page as a filter, try clicking on the "50% Off or more (10)" link.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow !!! Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: I have shared the link which I am working on in the previous comment. How do I show my work.

Comment: check your xpath, it should be  "//*[@id='ref_2665398031']/li[4]/a/span[1]"  and if using WebDriver then "//*[@id=\"ref_2665398031\"]/li[4]/a/span[1]"

Answer (score 0):

You have not properly written the xpath:
".//*[@id='ref_2665398031']/li[4]/a/span1"

it should be : "//*[@id='ref_2665398031']/li[4]/a/span[1]"
and if using WebDriver then 
"//*[@id=\"ref_2665398031\"]/li[4]/a/span[1]"

After correcting above if still error exists:

You are using a relative path which is relative to the element having `id='ref_2665398031`. 
This id seems to be generated dynamically.

Please confirm two things:

1. Your code is not giving element not found error.
2. Page refresh is not changing this id. (If it is being generated dynamically than it will change on page refresh.)

Otherwise try using different approach:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '50% Off or more')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ref_2665398031']/li[4]/a/span[1]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below xpath it is working for me

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'ref_2665398031')]/li[4]/a")).click();

Answer (score -1):

Try JavaScriptExecutor instead of using normal Selenium click method.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'50% Off or more')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: could you share screnshot of element and its dom

Comment: I am not able to share the screenshot but i have shared the link in the question part. pls check it out.